# How to inject common methods?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

In my angularjs controller, I have a lot of code that is very similar to this:

```
homeFactory.getApplicationData().then(function (response) {
    $scope.applicationdata = response.data;
}, function (error) {
    $scope.alerts.push({ type: 'error', msg: error.data.ExceptionMessage });
});
```

Where I make the call to my Web.API service and handle any errors.
The injected factory `homeFactory` looks like this:

```
app.factory('homeFactory', function ($http) {
    var factory = {};

    // Application Data
    factory.getApplicationData = function () {
        var url = "/tracker/api/applicationdata";
        return $http.get(url);
    };

    return factory;
});
```

I would like to refactor my code into something simpler, where instead of every method handling errors I just used one common method and inject it into every controller that may need data from the server.  So I was trying to create a factory like this:

```
app.factory('commonFactory', function ($scope) {
    var factory = {};

    factory.getData = function (method) {
        method.then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        }, function (error) {
            $scope.alerts.push({ type: 'error', msg: error.data.ExceptionMessage });
        });
    };

    return factory;
});
```

And inject this into my controller so that I could do something like this:

```
$scope.applicationdata = commonFactory.getData(homeFactory.getApplicationData());
```

But this doesn't work- it seems that $scope isn't happy about being injected in this case:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- commonFactory

So first, I was using a factory because I know that services are singletons and so $scope is clearly a problem there.  But I thought the factory was the right way to go.

What am I doing wrong and what's the best practice for this kind of code management?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can only inject instances to factory. You can use $rootScope

```
app.factory('commonFactory', function ($rootScope) {
```

Comment: Hmm, but I was hoping to use $scope in the getData function... if I use $rootScope then I have to manage my alerts at that level...?

Comment: @Nicros This is by design I think.

Comment: This seems to work just fine and accomplishes my goal.  It just requires that I reinitialize: `$rootScope.alerts =[];` on my controller init method.  Small price to pay :)